# How to get around assigning every variable in an inner loop with every iteration of an outer loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns in Excel, each has about about 500 strings. So A1 -> A500 and Y1 -> Y500.

I check if any of the strings in cells Y1 -> Y500 appear in cell A1 then A2 then A3 etc.

I have a loop inside another loop. For every iteration of the outer loop (A1, A2, A3....A500) the inner loop assigns 500 values to a variable (Y1, Y2, Y3...Y500), then checks if one variable contains the other. In total that is 1/4 million calculations.

Is there is a more refined way of doing it?

```
Sub search()
    Dim CForm As String
    Dim pos As Integer
    Dim CURL As String
    Dim Col As Integer
    Dim Pract As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    'Count the number of rows in column A
    Worksheets("Landing (both web & email)>").Select
    Col = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1
    'MsgBox Col
    'Count the number of rows in column Y
    Worksheets("Landing (both web & email)>").Select
    Pract = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("y:y")) + 1
    'MsgBox Pract
    'For loop, assigning variable CForm to the contents of cells in column A
    For i = 3 To Col
        CForm = Cells(i, 1)
        '2nd For loop, assigning variable CURL to the contents of cells in column Y
        For j = 3 To Pract
            CURL = Cells(j, 25)
            'Check to see if contents of variable CURL appear in variable CForm.
            pos = InStr(CForm, CURL)

            If pos > 0 Then
                Worksheets("Landing (both web & email)>").Range("t" & i).Value = "PractURL"
                Exit For
            Else
                Worksheets("Landing (both web & email)>").Range("t" & i).Value = ""
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim Col As Long, Pract As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim arr1, arr2, arr3
With Sheets("Landing (both web & email)>")
    Col = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Pract = .Range("Y" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    arr1 = Application.Transpose(.Range("A3:A" & Col))
    arr2 = Application.Transpose(.Range("Y3:Y" & Pract))
    ReDim arr3(LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr2))
    For j = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
        For k = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            If InStr(arr1(j), arr2(k)) <> 0 Then arr3(j) = "PractURL": Exit For
        Next k
    Next j
    .Range("T3:T" & Col) = Application.Transpose(arr3)
End With
```

Range to range comparison takes a while so what we did is to transfer Range values to arrays.
Column A to *arr1* and Column Y to *arr2*. Arrays to array comparison is way faster than the latter.
We dump the result to another array (*arr3*) which will then be passed to Column T.
As for speed, this took ***0.109 sec*** in my machine for *500* data with *100* matches. HTH.

Comment: That works really well, thank you for your input. Connor